# subprocess.Popen [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, subprocess

I work on few scripts I use in Stream. I did some and now I try to do a launcher that centralize all my Scripts.

I think I'm on a good way with subprocess, but I have some difficulties atm.

I try to launch a script with this line :

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', "E:/path/rocksmith/rocksmith.pyw"], shell=True)
```

But python give me a No such file or directory error.
In my script I want to launch (rocksmith.pyw) I open some text file with open() and I guess python can't find .txt file because the .txt isn't in the launcher directory right ?

My directory is like that :

```
Launcher folder
 - launcher.py
   * Script 1 folder
     - Script1.py
     - text.txt
   * Script 2 folder
     - Script2.py
     - text.txt
   * Script 3 folder
     - Script3.py
     - image.gif
```

I don't know if my explanation are ok or not.
I juste want to launch some script, in a "super script".

Thanks.

Comment: What do you see from `print(path.path+"/rocksmith/rocksmith.pyw")`?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's juste the absolute path to reach rocksmith.pyw E:/path/rocksmith/rocksmith.pyw

Comment: What's your `path.path`? How is its value assigned?

Comment: Is the "No such file or directory" occurring trying to run rocksmith.pyw or is it occurring when rocksmith.pyw tries to open a file?

Comment: when rocksmith.pyw try to open a file, sorry I'm not familiar with stackoverflow :/

Comment: Why `shell=True`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Popen error: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935151/popen-error-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error is occurring when `rocksmith.pyw` tries to open a file, you might want to use the `cwd` kwarg to `Popen`. This will change the working directory from where the script is run, so that relative paths in `rocksmith.pyw` will resolve as you expect.

```
subprocess.Popen(['python', "E:/path/rocksmith/rocksmith.pyw"], cwd='/path/to/rocksmith/stuff')
```

Comment: On UNIX, `shell=True` is actively harmful in this use case -- `python` alone would be parsed as a shell script, and the additional argument would be ignored because the script that's given in the first argument never looks at its subsequent arguments (doesn't refer to `$0`, `$1`, etc). Might not make a difference on Windows, though; command-line handling is... different there.