# Change Directory and Execute Command - Python

Tags: python, directory

I have been struggling a lot with this piece of code i wrote by referring tutorials:

```
    import os
    os.chdir(f'/home/django/image-io/accounts/john_doe/optimized/')
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    logger.info(f'CURRENT WORKING DIRECOTRY :{cwd}')
    subprocess.Popen(f"optimize-images")
```

What i am trying to do is dynamically change directory on username (john_doe) in this case and run a command optimize-images inside that directory to optimize all images .

It doesn't seem to work.

When i checked the logs , it says:

> optimize-images : "No such directory present"

I am not able to understand , where i am doing wrong. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code,  We are optimizing the images contained in the *optimized* folder.

```
import os
import subprocess
os.chdir(r'/home/django/image-io/accounts/john_doe/optimized')
cwd = os.getcwd()
p=subprocess.Popen([r"optimize-images", cwd])
```

---

We need to pass the the parameters in the array list format. You can get more details [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

> subprocess.Popen([r"optimize-images", cwd])

**Note:**

- **r** is used to indicate the raw string.
- **f** is used when we need to include the value of Python expressions inside strings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. did it work for you ? i mean locally.

Comment: Yeah. I created a python script with above lines and then executed it. Check your path whether it is Absolute path or Relative Path when passing the parameter to os.chdir() function.

Comment: It applies Lossless data compression Algorithm on Image to get it optimized for web usage.

Comment: Thanks. Another question just popped in my mind. I am using the image optimization code for a long running task where diffrent people will be calling this endpoint. Will it have any impact or all the subprocesses will be managed seperately. ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? [Popen error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9935151/popen-error-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Try `subprocess.Popen(f"optimize-images", shell = True)`